# error while configuring FFmpeg in CentOS: Segmentation fault & gcc is unable to create an executable file

Tags: centos, gcc, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile FFmpeg in CentOS from source code. I referenced the official compilation guide (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) for CentOS step by step, and have installed the listed dependencies. But when I tried to configure FFmpeg, I met with a problem as below:

[image]

The error lines (1249~1270) in file `configure` are:

```
check_exec(){
    check_ld "cc" "$@" && { enabled cross_compile || $TMPE >> $logfile 2>&1; }
}

check_exec_crash(){
    log check_exec_crash "$@"
    code=$(cat)

    # exit() is not async signal safe.  _Exit (C99) and _exit (POSIX)
    # are safe but may not be available everywhere.  Thus we use
    # raise(SIGTERM) instead.  The check is run in a subshell so we
    # can redirect the "Terminated" message from the shell.  SIGBUS
    # is not defined by standard C so it is used conditionally.

    (check_exec "$@") >> $logfile 2>&1 <<EOF
```

The config.log shows:

```
zscale_filter=yes
zscale_filter_deps=libzimg
mktemp -u XXXXXX
Ubjjqz
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.rgbbriKe.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.rgbbriKe.c
gcc -I/home/vis/guangli/local/include -c -o /tmp/ffconf.LLalSg6X.o /tmp/ffconf.rgbbriKe.c
gcc -L/home/vis/guangli/local/lib -ldl -o /tmp/ffconf.G3SYKa9M /tmp/ffconf.LLalSg6X.o
C compiler test failed.
```

My OS is CentOS x86_64, the gcc installed in system is gcc-4.4.6, but in order to compile FFmpeg with gcc-4.8.2, I add `GCC482_HOME/{bin,include}` to environment variables: `PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH` correspondingly.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but to eliminate the `tput` errors execute`export TERM=xterm` before running config. It seems that the terminfo database on this system does not have a definition for xterm-256color.

Comment: What about the message: `C compiler test failed` ?

Comment: I would fix the TERM variable and just try it. Is there a reason you're trying to compile it instead of maybe just getting the RPM from a source like http://repoforge.org/? You also might want to specify which CentOS release you are using. 5.X, 6.X, 7.X? `cat /etc/centos-release` or `cat /etc/lsb_release`.

Comment: I have fix the `tput` problem by exporting environmental variable `TERMINFO`. The message `C compiler test failed` still appears. The version of my CentOS is `6.3`. The output of  `cat /etc/centos-release` is `CentOS release 6.3 (Final)`. Because I need to distribute the libraries of FFmpeg to other machines, so I have to compile it myself.  （＞﹏＜）

Comment: Could you confirm that creating that source file and then running those commands actually results in a segfault? If so, what if you take off the `-L/home/vis/guangli/local/lib` ?

Comment: I am not sure how to confirm the cause of  segmentation fault, any advice ?

Comment: I said to change `TERM`, not `TERMINFO`. Do you still get the `tput: unknown terminal error`?
The issue may be mixing gcc libs and includes from two releases.

Comment: @Beanocean just run that compile again: `echo "int main(void){ return 0; }" > /tmp/ffconf.rgbbriKe.c && gcc -I/home/vis/guangli/local/include -c -o /tmp/ffconf.LLalSg6X.o /tmp/ffconf.rgbbriKe.c && gcc -L/home/vis/guangli/local/lib -ldl -o /tmp/ffconf.G3SYKa9M /tmp/ffconf.LLalSg6X.o` ... see if you get a segfault (you should). Then take off the `-L…` option and see if it remains.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to `export TERM=xterm`, but it didn't work. After exporting the `TERMINFO`, the error: `tput: unknown terminal` doesn't appear any more.

Comment: Also: `command -v gcc` — are you using the system compiler, or something else?

Comment: @derobert The gcc version info is `gcc (GCC) 4.8.2`. And there is no compile error when running `echo "int main(void){ return 0; }" > /tmp/ffconf.rgbbriKe.c && gcc -I/home/vis/guangli/local/include -c -o /tmp/ffconf.LLalSg6X.o /tmp/ffconf.rgbbriKe.c && gcc -L/home/vis/guangli/local/lib -ldl -o /tmp/ffconf.G3SYKa9M /tmp/ffconf.LLalSg6X.o`. But when I tried to run the executable file `/tmp/ffconf.G3SYKa9M`, the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: If I try to add the path `$GCC482/lib`  to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, many of shell commands would fail with segmentation faults.

Comment: @Beanocean well, it sounds like you've got some broken libraries. Where did those libraries come from? Or that compiler (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19458 says it ships with 4.4.x)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60080/discussion-between-beanocean-and-derobert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out (for reasons yet unknown) that any executable placed in `/tmp` on your system segfaults. Even `cp /bin/ls /tmp && cd /tmp && ./ls` gives an `ls` that segfaults. But if moved to your home directory, then it works.

That is breaking configure; the obvious workaround is to create a subdirectory of your home directory and set TMPDIR to that.