# Segmentation Fault in System Directory `/tmp`

Tags: centos, tmp, segmentation-fault

When compiling FFmpeg, the configuring failed because of a segmentation fault in exec checking. I posted my problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369760/error-while-configuring-ffmpeg-in-centos-segmentation-fault-gcc-is-unable-to), and I solved my problem by exporting a new `TMPDIR`.

What's weird is the segmentation fault only happened in the directory `/tmp`. The test executable compiled in configuration stage was placed in `/tmp`, and a segmentation fault occurred. If I placed the executable in the sub-directory of my `$HOME`, everything seemed OK. Even if the command `cp /bin/ls /tmp/ && cd /tmp/ && ./ls` would cause a segmentation fault.

What's the possible causes?

Comment: There are some ideas at https://serverfault.com/questions/625248/ls-causes-segmentation-fault-on-a-specific-directory.

Comment: `/tmp` mounted `noexec`?

Comment: BTW: The previous question generated this chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60080/discussion-between-beanocean-and-derobert

Comment: @SatoKatsura the mount options (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37960633#37960633) don't show noexec.

Comment: Hmm.  Then perhaps get a core dump and a see where the crash happens.